# Despite Angular works correct on local, doesnt work after build

Tags: javascript, angular, build

I created a simple gallery by `ngFor` and add `onclick` function on each rendered image that works correctly on localhost but after build, each click will has `` ERROR ReferenceError: "can't access lexical declaration `n' before initialization" ``

ts file:

```
 images = [
   {title: 't1', src: "images/img1.jpg"},
   {title: 't2', src: "images/img2.jpg"},
   {title: 't3', src: "images/img3.jpg"}
 ]

  showImg(index) {
    console.log(index);
  }
```

and in html file:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="imagesWrapper">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" *ngFor="let item of images; let i = index">
            <img [src]="item.src" class="gallery-image" (click)="showImg(i)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

again should say that it works correct on localhost based on ng serve but after build I have error for every click

my console error:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: "can't access lexical declaration `n' before initialization"
    showImg http://example.com/newfolder/main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js:1
    Kr http://example.com/newfolder/main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js:1
    handleEvent http://example.com/newfolder/main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js:1
    handleEvent http://example.com/newfolder/main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js:1
    Qp http://example.com/newfolder/main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js:1
    Ob http://example.com/newfolder/main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js:1
    G http://example.com/newfolder/main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js:1
    invokeTask http://example.com/newfolder/polyfills-es2015.76d7601b4ebbcc8becab.js:1
    onInvokeTask http://example.com/newfolder/main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js:1
    invokeTask http://example.com/newfolder/polyfills-es2015.76d7601b4ebbcc8becab.js:1
    runTask http://example.com/newfolder/polyfills-es2015.76d7601b4ebbcc8becab.js:1
    invokeTask http://example.com/newfolder/polyfills-es2015.76d7601b4ebbcc8becab.js:1
    y http://example.com/newfolder/polyfills-es2015.76d7601b4ebbcc8becab.js:1
    k http://example.com/newfolder/polyfills-es2015.76d7601b4ebbcc8becab.js:1
main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js:1:52398
    br http://example.com/newfolder/main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js:1
    handleError
```

and a part of the main-es2015.0dfa8e3b51a3bf4afbe1.js file:

```
{title:"t3",src:this."images/img3.jpg"}]}ngOnInit(){}showImg(e){n=document.getElementById("imagesWrapper").children[e].children[0]
```

Comment: What you posted should work. I'm guessing your problem is related specifically to building (probably with AoT !?) and something that's normally available in serve (because the compiler is available) is not there in the minified version. Try to build unminified and check if any of your dev packages is required in prod. Also look closely in console for any errors during build. In current form your question does not contain sufficient detail to be answerable.

Comment: thanks for your replay, I've added detail of console error and I have no idea whats happening coz everything is correct on local

Comment: Have you tried any [alternative syntax](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)?

Comment: The same is happening for me. And it was working with Angular 7 but after upgrade this is failing. Works fine with ng serve. So must be AOT.

Comment: @HamaBohel How did you fix this issue?

Comment: For me the issues was in NgRX where I was modifying read-only properties.